# totem player shows controls for few seconds in full screen

Tags: fullscreen, totem

I am trying to run a video via terminal using `totem`, however, even though the `--fullscreen` flag is given, the controls flick for a few seconds before going real full screen.

Is it possible to avoid showing the controls at all using `totem`?

my command:

```
>> totem --fullscreen "$TEST_VIDEO" &
```